# JavaFX - subscript and superscript text in TextFlow

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have been trying to get simple rich text in JavaFX: I wish for continuous text where some characters are bold, subscript, or superscript. This is impossible in the normal Text or Label classes. I have tried `WebView` with no success, as although it will display such text, it does not size to its contents, and thus takes up an uncontrollably large portion of the screen.

Now I am attempting to use a `TextFlow`. I can successfully link together `Text` objects, some of which can be made bold. However, subscript and superscript are proving more difficult. Subscript can be emulated simply by reducing the font size, however superscript needs that `Text` object to be raised above the others. I cannot find a way of doing this: `TextFlow` specifically ignores translation properties of the `Text` objects, and I cannot override `getBaselineOffset()` on the `Text` in question, as it is final.

Am I going to have to put the `Text`s in an HBox? Is there really no support for this in JavaFX? What I am trying to do is not complex; it seems mind-boggling that there is no native support for subscript and superscript.

```
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class TextFlowBuilder
{
private static final String BOLD = "<b>";
private static final String UN_BOLD = "</b>";

private static final String SUPERSCRIPT = "<sup>";
private static final String UN_SUPERSCRIPT = "</sup>";

private static final String SUBSCRIPT = "<sub>";
private static final String UN_SUBSCRIPT = "</sub>";

private static final Pattern NOT_JUST_WHITESPACE = Pattern.compile("\\S");
private static final Pattern CHARACTER_CODE = Pattern.compile("&#(\\d+);");

public static TextFlow htmlToTextFlow(final String html, final int fontSize, final TextAlignment alignment)
{
    final String[] split = html.split("(?<=>)|(?=<)");  //Split before and after tags, splitting it into a series of tags and tag contents.
    final List<Text> texts = new LinkedList<>();

    boolean b = false;
    boolean sup = false;
    boolean sub = false;

    for (String segment : split)
    {
        switch (segment)
        {
            case BOLD:
                b = true;
                break;
            case UN_BOLD:
                b = false;
                break;
            case SUPERSCRIPT:
                sup = true;
                break;
            case UN_SUPERSCRIPT:
                sup = false;
                break;
            case SUBSCRIPT:
                sub = true;
                break;
            case UN_SUBSCRIPT:
                sub = false;
                break;

            default:
                //Add as text if string is not a tag, and is more than just whitespace.
                if (segment.length() > 0
                        && NOT_JUST_WHITESPACE.matcher(segment).find()
                        && !segment.startsWith("<"))
                {
                    final Matcher m = CHARACTER_CODE.matcher(segment);
                    while (m.find())
                    {
                        final String specialChar = Character.toString((char)Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));
                        segment = m.replaceFirst(specialChar);
                    }

                    final Text t = new Text(segment);
                    String style = "";
                    if (b)
                        style += "-fx-font-weight: bold; ";
                    if (sup)
                    {
                        style += String.format("-fx-font-size: %f.3; ", fontSize/1.75);
                        //Need to move text to above the rest
                    }
                    else if (sub)
                    {
                        style += String.format("-fx-font-size: %f.3; ", fontSize/1.75);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        style += String.format("-fx-font-size: %d; ", fontSize);
                    }
                    t.setStyle(style);
                    texts.add(t);
                }
        }
    }

    final Text[] textsAsArray = new Text[texts.size()];
    final TextFlow tf = new TextFlow(texts.toArray(textsAsArray));
    tf.setTextAlignment(alignment);
    return tf;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the translateY property (in code, not sure about via CSS) on the text objects does indeed work - perhaps something has changed about it since the question was asked.

Here's a demonstration:

```
    TextFlow container = new TextFlow();
    Text normal = new Text("Normal");
    Text sup = new Text("sup");
    Text sub = new Text("sub");
    sup.setTranslateY(normal.getFont().getSize() * -0.3);
    sub.setTranslateY(normal.getFont().getSize() * 0.3);
    container.getChildren().addAll(normal, sup, sub);
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Subscript and superscript via setTranslateY on Text in TextFlow]

I am using JavaFX 11 on a Mac, in case that ends up making a difference to whether or not this actually works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-fx-translate-y`
You can control the text up and down
You can also use RichTextFX
that can be used to create an editable text area with varying styles and with Superscript and Subscript support

Comment: As stated in the question, "TextFlow specifically ignores translation properties of the Text objects". Thus, this does not work. You can hack around it by putting translated *Label* objects in the TextFlow, but you still need to fiddle with the translation based on the font size, and it's really not a neat solution. I'm asking if there is a better way.